# Creating a file which contain the current time as the file name

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2019

I have to create a file where the filename should contain the time as its name

In general we create a file called **Sample.txt** but now I have to create a file called **Sample-12:35:07.txt** using visual studio c++

Please help mee!
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a [mcve] of your attempt to show us? What's the problem with your attempt? How does it work or not work? Also please read or refresh about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As a couple of hints: Please read about [`std::chrono::system_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock), [`std::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) and [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: you rock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in one of the comments, for this purpose you should use following:

- `std::time` return the current calendar time
- `std::localtime` converts given time since epoch (object of type `std::time_t` we got from `std::time`) value into calendar time, expressed in local time
- `std::put_time` converts the date and time information from `std::tm` pointer (first argument) to a string according to the format string (second argument); it is a stream manipulator which means it can be used along with `std::ostringstream`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    auto t = std::time(nullptr);
    auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(&tm, "%H-%M-%S");
    auto current_time = oss.str();

    std::string filename = "Sample-" + current_time + ".txt";

    std::cout << filename << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:40,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:40,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:40,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:40,startLineNumber:16),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciomanip%3E%0A%23include+%3Cctime%3E%0A%23include+%3Csstream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+t+%3D+std::time(nullptr)%3B%0A++++auto+tm+%3D+*std::localtime(%26t)%3B%0A%0A++++std::ostringstream+oss%3B%0A++++oss+%3C%3C+std::put_time(%26tm,+%22%25H-%25M-%25S%22)%3B%0A++++auto+current_time+%3D+oss.str()%3B%0A%0A++++std::string+filename+%3D+%22Sample-%22+%2B+current_time+%2B+%22.txt%22%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+filename+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:56.69638920801932,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'0'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:cmcstl2,ver:trunk)),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-O3',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:43.303610791980674,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:43.303610791980674,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: I also try using C++20 `std::format` to format the string but could find the right compiler version that supports it already so I left this simple solution. Also, if this answer helped you, please accept it as the correct one (clicking the tick at the left side of the answer).

Comment: @Jaya madhu Please, don't try to reply to my answer through an edit. Edit your question instead. If VS warns you about the usage of `localtime` and not `localtime_s`, just put this `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` on top of your file. I am not a VS expert but this would make it working (I believe so)